# Android app that counts multiple events on a timeline

Tags: android, project-management, monitoring

I would like to track my stomach's response to food intake... with an automatic reference to timing. There are a number of responses I would like to keep track of. Again with a time reference of when during a day.

Does anyone know an app where you can enter (and therefore count) multiple 'events' which automatically relate to the time and date when they occurred?

Many thanks for your advice.

Maria, Sydney